# C enum using macros

Tags: c

In glibc source code, I found that some enumeration definitions include macro definitions. For example:

```
// file: glibc/stdlib/fmtmsg.h
enum
{
  MM_HARD = 0x001,  /* Source of the condition is hardware.  */
#define MM_HARD MM_HARD
  MM_SOFT = 0x002,  /* Source of the condition is software.  */
#define MM_SOFT MM_SOFT
...
};
```

and

```
// file: glibc/bits/confname.h
enum
  {
    _PC_LINK_MAX,
#define _PC_LINK_MAX            _PC_LINK_MAX
    _PC_MAX_CANON,
#define _PC_MAX_CANON           _PC_MAX_CANON
    _PC_MAX_INPUT,
#define _PC_MAX_INPUT           _PC_MAX_INPUT
...
}
```

Since the syntax of the text macro replacement is

```
#define identifier replacement-list
```

But in the above example, identifier is the same as replacement-list. what's the point?

EDITED:
I tried to search _PC_LINK_MAX with `grep -r`, here is the result:

```
bits/confname.h:    _PC_LINK_MAX,
bits/confname.h:#define _PC_LINK_MAX                    _PC_LINK_MAX
ChangeLog.old/ChangeLog.9:      * sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/alpha/fpathconf.c: Handle _PC_LINK_MAX here.
conform/data/unistd.h-data:constant _PC_LINK_MAX
manual/conf.texi:@item _PC_LINK_MAX
posix/annexc.c:  "_PC_ASYNC_IO", "_PC_CHOWN_RESTRICTED", "_PC_LINK_MAX", "_PC_MAX_CANON",
posix/fpathconf.c:    case _PC_LINK_MAX:
posix/getconf.c:    { "LINK_MAX", _PC_LINK_MAX, PATHCONF },
posix/getconf.c:    { "_POSIX_LINK_MAX", _PC_LINK_MAX, PATHCONF },
sysdeps/posix/fpathconf.c:    case _PC_LINK_MAX:
sysdeps/posix/pathconf.c:    case _PC_LINK_MAX:
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fpathconf.c:    case _PC_LINK_MAX:
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pathconf.c:    case _PC_LINK_MAX:
```

Comment: Possibly so that `#ifdef _PC_LINK_MAX` will work?

Comment: @NateEldredge I searched the entire project with grep, and there was no such statement.

Comment: It would be for application code, not within glibc.  If for instance the `_PC_LINK_MAX` constant is available on some platforms but not others, application code can use `#ifdef _PC_LINK_MAX` to wrap code that depends on it.

Comment: @NateEldredge, how would that work? If the enum is defined, the def is also defined, always. An `ifdef` would always be true.

Comment: Compare to a different platform that doesn't use glibc at all.  On such a platform, there might be no `_PC_LINK_MAX` in that enum; such a platform would hopefully not define the macro either, so the `#ifdef` would be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very common workaround. It allows programmer to use macro directives (especially `#if`) to generate the code if type or enum was declared.

In other standard header files you can see

```
#ifndef _UINT32_T_DECLARED
typedef __uint32_t uint32_t ;
#define _UINT32_T_DECLARED
#endif
```

Example usage:

```
#if defined(_UINT32_T_DECLARED)
typedef my32 uint32_t;
#else
typedef my32 unsigned long;
#endif

#ifdef MM_SOFT
myfunc(MM_SOFT);
#else
#error Required enum missing.
#endif
```